# Self replacing object python

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to create an object that is capable of replacing itself with an arbitrary object when accessed; as in the following:

```
class stand_in_object(object):
    def __init__(self,obj_ref):
        self.obj_ref

    def __getattr__(self,key):
        pass
        #somehow make calling reference now refer to self.obj_ref
        #Consider: setattr(ref,name,self.obj_ref) - how do I get ref,name?
        #Or perhaps something that replaces the object located at "location"
        #so that all references id(self) are "pointing" to
        #a new object. Maybe ctypes.memmove?

#------------------------Example use----------------------
class x(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.y=stand_in_object(int(5))

a=x()
print a.x.f #calls a.x.__getattr__('f') which sets a.x = int(5)
```

I was thinking I could try either the memmove, or replace all references method found this post: https://benkurtovic.com/2015/01/28/python-object-replacement.html

I'm attempting to make an OODB using cPickle. I would like to have persistent objects that have not been loaded, be referenced by a stand-in object until they are accessed. Something like the following:

```
loaded = {}
class stand_in(object):
    def __init__(self,id,src): 
        self.id,self.src = id,src
    def __getattr__(self,key):
        loaded[self.id] = cust_unpickle(self.src)
    #Some function to replace reference of standin_obj with loaded object

def persistent_load(id):
    if id in loaded: return loaded[id]
    else: return stand_in(id,src)

#--------------------------Example-------------------------------
#consider database stores objects a and c, and a.c = c.
a = unpickle(a.id,src) #loaded = {a.id:a}, a.c = stand_in(c.id,c.src)
print a.c.x  #calls a.c.__gettattr__ which has the effect:
             #c = unpickle(c.id,src)
             #and loads = {a.id:a,c.id:c}
```